# Projective dimension of module over local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

This question arose reading the well known article by Buchsbaum *Lectures on regular local rings*.

> He states without proof that, given $(R,m)$ a local ring and an $R$-module $M$ over $R$, we have the inequality:
>   $$\mathrm{projdim}(M)\leq \mathrm{projdim}(R/m).$$

I think this is rather simple, but I can't figure out how to produce a proof. If we take a projective resolution $P_\bullet$ of $M$, how can I tell that its length is less or equal to $\mathrm{projdim}(R/m)$?

Thank you for help, I think I need only some hints and I'll fill the details.

**Edit.** I would like to point that in Buchsbaum's article $R$ and $M$ are apparently taken without any other condition than $R$ being local (and noetherian).

Comment: If I didn't write any condition, I obviously meant that $M$ is an arbitrary $R$-module and $R$ an arbitrary local ring.

Comment: @Alexander, no it is not obvious —an immense number of questions asked in this site are missing hypotheses. Please, when asked for clarifications on your questions here be nice and comply.

Comment: For example, it is not clear at all whether your local rings are noetherian or not —some people include neotherianity in the definition of local rings, others do not, and it is always a good idea to make clear in which group you are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that the projective dimension of the module $R/m$ is equal to the global dimension of the ring $R$. This is done in textbooks, like C. Weibel's *Introduction to homological algebra* or in Cartan-Eilenberg's *Homological Algebra*.

(This is for noetherian local rings)

Comment: I would not call this a «rather simple» result, really... In particular, you cannot proceed by «taking a projective resolutio of $M$ and comparing it to the projective dimensin of $R/m$».